# Python 3.6.1 - Printing string as human readable text, special characters

Tags: python, string, encoding, locale, decoding

I'm building a little django 1.1 app (though I believe this issue to be specific to Python) where I've come to use commands to control the flow of getting and categorizing data. I also wish to print a sort of summary using a third command. I am using macOS 10.12.3

My problem comes from getting text data in and printing it to the console or a document using

```
> or >>
```

in the console.

I'm running these scripts using an alias of Python 3.6.1

I'm using the Tweepy api, but that should hopefully not be relevant.

These snippets should illustrate the problem I'm hoping to solve:

```
print(type(data))
print(type(data.text))
try:
    print(data.text)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print("no printing today :(")
print(type(data.text.encode('UTF-8')))
print(data.text.encode('UTF-8'))
```

this outputs:

```
<class 'tweepy.models.Status'>
<class 'str'>
no printing today :(
<class 'bytes'>
b'kontroll p\xc3\xa5 ... v\xc3\xa5pen.'
```

The ugly things there should both be the character 'å'.

This is the error that would be thrown:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in position 223: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It says 'ascii' codec, but doing (in my Python 3.6.1 script):

```
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

outputs:

```
utf-8
```

Running

```
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

again in Python 2.7.10 outputs:

```
ascii
```

So the thrown error matches what 2.7.10 outputs. I am not discounting the possibility that I could be wrong about what a default encoder does

I have also tried

```
export LOCALE="no_NB.UTF-8"
```

in an attempt to see if this could be caused by my system (unless I'm misunderstanding what this does). I did not write this to any file, thinking it would persist through the current session.

Is the wrong encoder being used somehow? Could it be my terminal encoding? How can I write my special characters to the terminal and file? Are strings really this hard to get right?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The problem is likely that your *terminal emulator* doesn't support unicode characters, or is set to encode with ASCII, hence the `UnicodeEncode` error when you *print*. When you `.encode` a string, it returns a `bytes` object, which will always have an "ugly" representation for bytes outside the ascii ordinal range... unless you *decode it * (or in your case, refrain from encoding it).

Comment: Are you sure this `"no_NB.UTF-8"` is an available locale? Try `locale -a | grep "no_NB.UTF-8"` in your shell. I couldn't find it on my machine, (osx 10.12.4), but I did find `no_NO.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting

```
export LC_ALL=no_NO.UTF-8
export LANG=no_NO.UTF-8
```

in my .bash_profile now allows me to see the characters I want in my terminal and it is also successfully echoed to a file.